# Laravel - Save on eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eloquent

I have 3 models **User**, **Store**, **MerchantProduct**.

User has many stores
Stores has many MerchantProduct
MerchantProduct belongs to user and store

I want to be able to save `user_id` and `store_id` in `merchantproduct` table

User Model

```
class User extends BaseModel { 
  public function stores()
  { 
   return $this->hasMany(Store::class);
  } 
  public function products()
  { 
   return $this->hasMany(MerchantProduct::class);
  } 
}
```

Store Model

```
class Store extends BaseModel { 
  public function owner()
  { 
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
  public function merchantProducts()
  { 
   return $this->hasMany(MerchantProduct::class);
  }
}
```

Merchant Model

```
class MerchantProduct extends BaseModel { 
  public function owner()
  { 
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
  public function store()
  { 
   return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
  }
}
```

I have tried to use the code below to save but I'm getting Call to

> undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::merchantProducts() error

```
$request->user()->stores()->merchantProducts()->create($request->all());
```

What's the correct/right way to do this

Comment: `dd($request->user()->stores())`  if result one collection you can do this else you mus use `$request->user()->stores->merchantProducts()`

Comment: Doesn't the store_id functionally determine the user_id? It might be less of a headache if you normalized this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't add `user_id` and `owner()` relationship to the `MerchantProduct` model.

But if you want to do that, save `MerchantProduct` object with manually adding user ID:

```
Store::merchantProducts()->create(['user_id' => auth()->id()] + $request->all());
```

Also, add the `user_id` to the `$fillable` array in the `MerchantProduct` model.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this method but still getting the same error I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with very simple approach. As your `store` model has already an `user_id` then you can just loop through the `store` collection and save to `DB`.

```
($request->user()->stores() as $store){
    $merchant_product = new MerchantProduct();
    $merchant_product->user_id = $store->user_id;
    $merchant_product->store_id = $store->id;
    //your other fields go here as you want to insert to merchant product
    $merchant_product->save();
}
```